# about the figure with java applet

Tags: java

i wanna write a program to show a figure in a window by java and the program can be compiled and run without an error, however, the figure can not be seen in the window. what's wrong with the code? thanks a lot.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
public class MyApp extends Applet implements ImageObserver
{
Image img;

String imgPath="C:\\2000.JPEG";
int xpoint=50,ypoint=50;
public void init()
{
    setBackground(Color.blue);
    setForeground(Color.green);
    imgPath="C:\\2000_CannotViewImage.gif";
    }
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    URL imgURL=getDocumentBase();
    img=getImage(imgURL,imgPath);
    g.drawImage(img, xpoint, ypoint, this);
}


}
```

Comment: Remove the c:\\ if you're trying to get the image from the web server where the jar is located.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Swing or AWT well so I can't help much with that part.

You won't be able to access the local hard disk without signing the applet. That's a tricky process. To avoid going through that put the image in the JAR and use getResourceAsStream() to get to it.

Wrap everything in paint() in a try-catch and print out the exception if one occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class MyImage extends Applet{
    private java.awt.Image image1;
    public void init(){
        image1=getImage(getDocumentBase(),"android.png");
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(image1,0,0,this);
    }
}
```

Comment: This assumes there is an image on the web server in the same path as where the applet jars are deployed to. This won't work if you're running it in an IDE or maybe using appletviewer. Not saying it's wrong, just explaining how it works.

Comment: I see now he was calling getDocumentBase() too.